# Getting user's daily route in Android?

Tags: java, android, geolocation, locationmanager

I need to get the route a user goes through every day. I thought of checking the user's location every few minutes for 2-3 days and then analyze the information and get the origin and destination the user's going from and to every day.

The question is how will it affect battery life and is there a better way to do it. Are there any Android services that save the user's location history that I can access for this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a broadcast receiver from the location manager to send you a broad cast if the location has actually changed. While I was working on something similar myself I found this blog post to be very helpful http://android-developers.blogspot.nl/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html